# How to escape special char in filename

Tags: android, android-file

I want to load a file in my app and copy it to my app folder.
But, when filename contains space or special chars, it fail.
I'm using filter
Here my code :

**Manifest**

```
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf" />
        <data android:host="*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**MyActivity**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent != null) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action != null && action.compareTo(Intent.ACTION_VIEW) == 0) {
        String scheme = intent.getScheme();
        if (scheme.compareTo(ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE) == 0) {
            Uri uri = intent.getData();
            String name = uri.getLastPathSegment();

            String filepath = getPath() + name;
            // file name = "test café.pdf"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have something similar in one of my applications:

```
 String filepath = getPath() + removeAccents(name);
```

I did this function, that works on all APIS:

```
public static String removeAccents(String s){       
    try{    
        s = s.toLowerCase();
        if(VERSION.SDK_INT >  Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO){
            s = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
            s = s.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
        } else{
            s = s.replace("á", "a").replace("é", "e").replace("í", "i").replace("ó", "o").replace("ú", "u").replace("ñ", "n");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    return s;
}
```